# How to save an array of data that can be accessed whenever required?

Tags: arrays, swift, core-data, nsuserdefaults

I have a simple quiz app that I've started to develop, and would like to save the users progress if the app is force quit and reopened.

I have a class called 'Question' that is made up of variable Strings and one enum called 'Film' with three cases. I have created questions, and then add those questions into an array.

Within my code itself I have ensured that once a question is asked it is taken out of my 'allQuestions' array, and then added into a new array called 'usedQuestions'.

What I want to do is to then save my array of 'usedQuestions', and to then be able to load those questions as and when the app loads.

I have explored using UserDefaults, but looks like this is not possible, and I have also looked at using CoreData, but am currently struggling to get this to work as well.

```
//Class: 
class Question {

    var questionBody: String
    var correctAnswer: String
    var wrongAnswer: String
    var wrongAnswerTwo: String
    var wrongAnswerThree: String
    let filmTitle: Film

    enum Film {
         case one, two, three
    }

let firstQuestion = Question(questionBody: "This is question one", correctAnswer: "Correct", wrongAnswer: "Wrong Answer", wrongAnswerTwo: "Wrong Answer Two", wrongAnswerThree: "Wrong Answer Three", filmTitle: ".one"
let secondQuestion = Question(questionBody: "This is question Two", correctAnswer: "Correct", wrongAnswer: "Wrong Answer", wrongAnswerTwo: "Wrong Answer Two", wrongAnswerThree: "Wrong Answer Three", filmTitle: ".two"
let thirdQuestion = Question(questionBody: "This is question Three", correctAnswer: "Correct", wrongAnswer: "Wrong Answer", wrongAnswerTwo: "Wrong Answer Two", wrongAnswerThree: "Wrong Answer Three", filmTitle: ".three"

let allQuestions = [firstQuestion, secondQuestion, thirdQuestion]

//Code: 
var usedQuestions = [Question]()
var storedQuestion = Question(questionBody: "", correctAnswer: "", wrongAnswer: "", wrongAnswerTwo: "", wrongAnswerThree: "", filmTitle: .one)

func saveQuestionAsked(storedQuestion: Question) {
        let savedQuestion = storedQuestion
        usedQuestions.insert(savedQuestion, at: 0)
    }

let chosenQuestion = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(allQuestions.count)))
storedQuestion = allQuestions[chosenQuestion]
saveQuestionAsked(storedQuestion: allQuestions[chosenQuestion])
allQuestions.remove(at: chosenQuestion)
```

With the above code I have removed the 'storedQuestion' from the 'allQuestions' array, and then inserted it into the 'usedQuestion' array.

I now want to be able to save the questions in that array, so that when a user comes back, those questions still exist in that array.

Comment: While Core Data is the native solution, it is considerably more involved than something like Realm, a third-party solution that is much easier to set up and some argue is better than Core Data. Realm has a huge following and is definitely something you should look into before going forward. https://realm.io/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I've taken a look through their website - and although it appears to be a simple solution, I'm not looking to pay $30 a month for their basic package as I'm just working on this as a hobby! If for whatever reason I need something similar to this in the future, I'll definitely take a look! Thanks again

Comment: https://realm.io/products/realm-database/ the database is 100% free, the platfrom with hosting is not. This is a total Core Data replacement.